# How to use System.IDisposable.Dispose?

Tags: vb.net

Im getting a warning in my object which transfers value from one form to another
The warning said Button1 must call System.IDisposable.Dispose on Object Form1 before references  to it are of scope

This is my code on my button1:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form1 As New Form1
    Form1.a1 = TextBox1.Text
    Form1.a2 = TextBox2.Text
    Form1.a3 = TextBox3.Text
    Form1.a4 = TextBox4.Text
    Form1.a5 = TextBox5.Text
    Form1.a6 = TextBox6.Text
    Form1.a7 = TextBox7.Text
    Form1.a8 = TextBox8.Text
    Form1.a9 = TextBox9.Text
    Form1.a10 = TextBox10.Text
    Form1.Show()
    Form1.SetPrice()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

How to use System.IDisposable.Dispose?

Comment: You should *not* dispose the Form1 object.  Doing so will prevent you from ever seeing the window.  You didn't document your question well but CA2000 is notoriously unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the listed code is not in Form1.  Whatever form it's in is instantiating a Form1, but not disposing it.  Just wrap Form1 in a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement:

```
Using Form1 As New Form1
    Form1.a1 = TextBox1.Text
    Form1.a2 = TextBox2.Text
    Form1.a3 = TextBox3.Text
    Form1.a4 = TextBox4.Text
    Form1.a5 = TextBox5.Text
    Form1.a6 = TextBox6.Text
    Form1.a7 = TextBox7.Text
    Form1.a8 = TextBox8.Text
    Form1.a9 = TextBox9.Text
    Form1.a10 = TextBox10.Text
    Form1.Show()
    Form1.SetPrice()
End Using
Me.Close()
```